# Retrieve bash error from NodeJS child_process.spawn

Tags: node.js, bash, child-process

When I execute the (made up and ridiculous) command `banana` from bash I get the following error:

```
bash: banana: command not found
```

But if I execute `banana` in a `child_process.spawn` in Node.js, I get the error:

```
net.js:624
    throw new TypeError('invalid data');
          ^
TypeError: invalid data
    at WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:624:11)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> 
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1065:12)
    at child_process.js:1137:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Is there any way to get the text of the original bash error from Node.JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attaching to the 'error' event emitter for the child_process.spawn will give you the following message:

```
child_process_instance.on('error', function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});

Error: spawn bananas ENOENT
```